# Access the user's selection from a previous cmdlet

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm writing a script that I want to be able to react depending on the user's answer to a confirmation prompt that is part of a cmdlet being run in the script. For example:

```
Stop-Process -Name notepad -Confirm
if ($userresposne -eq "Yes") {echo "R.I.P. Notepad"} else {echo "Notepad lives to fight another day"}
```

I need to know what I should be using in place of `$userresponse` to call up the user's input to the confirmation prompt in `Stop-Process`. (Once this is known, I'm sure I can figure out what should properly be used in place of `"Yes"`.) Is there a way to do this?

I'm working in PowerShell 3.0 but I need the script to be backward-compatible to 2.0.

The key here is that I *don't* want to have to write my own prompting mechanism into the script. I'm aware that there are ways to do this, and I've done so in other scripts. However, since `Stop-Process` is already capable of prompting the user for the input that I need, adding those extra lines here would seem a little redundant.

In batch scripting, I'd probably be looking for something like the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable. Is there something similar that I could use here?

Answer (score 2):

The stop-process cmdlet supports a -passthru switch which might be useful in this circumstance

so you could assign

> $processresult = Stop-Process -Name notepad -Confirm -Passthru
>
> if ($processresult.name -eq "notepad") {echo "R.I.P. Notepad"} else {echo "Notepad lives"}

if the user choose to stop the process (i.e. enters Y) then $processresult will be a Process object.  If the user chooses not to end the process (i.e. enters n) it won't be. so test the resulting object and base it on that.

A bit hacky but should work.

Comment: Alternative condition for the if: `$processresult -ne $null`. This will work for my particular use case. Also, you might want to temporarily set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to keep PowerShell from barfing at the user when they pick "No". It would still be great if there's a method that works for the more general case, or if someone can verify that there isn't.

Comment: Scratch the bit about `$ErrorActionPreference`. That applies to a different part of the script I'm writing. `$Notepad = Get-Process notepad; while ($Notepad -ne $null) {$Notepad = Get-Process notepad}; echo 'Notepad is finally dead!'` will announce an error when Notepad is finally dead unless you change `$ErrorActionPreference`.

Comment: Interestingly, you can do without the $processresult variable entirely. `if ((Stop-Process -Name notepad -Confirm -Passthru) -ne $null) {echo "R.I.P. Notepad"} else {echo "Notepad lives"}`

Answer (score 1):

Writing an extra bit of code for input handling isn't that big of a deal. For example,

```
$input = Read-Host "Would you like to kill notepad?"

if($input.ToLower() -eq "yes") {
    Stop-Process -Name notepad
    Write-Host "R.I.P. Notepad"
} else {
    Write-Host "Notepad lives to fight another day"
}
```

Would work just fine and wouldn't add a ton to your script.

Comment: It's still redundant of the functionality provided by `Stop-Process -Name notepad -Confirm`. I'd rather have confirmation that I *can't* access the user input for `Stop-Process` before I fall back to writing my own confirmation prompt. (Even then, for this particular use case, I personally prefer @RoryMcCune's workaround.)

Comment: @Iszi i guess if literally all you are going to use the input for is to confirm the `Stop-Process` then @RoryMcCune's answer is a bit smoother. Even if it is a bit hackety hack. With input handling you could supply a reason for killing notepad, or even supply the process to kill.

Comment: For my particular case, I don't need the user to supply a reason or the process. I have a particular application that is not multi-user friendly. So, if someone is already logged on to the server and running the application on their session I will not be able to run it on mine. I'm trying to automate the task of identifying who's running the application and (optionally) terminating their instance. If I choose to terminate it, I want the script to run the application afterward. If I choose not to terminate, the script should exit.